# “How to fix "Class 'SplString' not found”

Tags: php

I try use a [SplString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splstring.php) and get error "Class 'SplString' not found"... How can I resolve the problem?

I'm using PHP7.3 from terminal...

```
<?php
$string = new SplString("Testing");

echo $string; // Outputs "Testing"
```

I expect the output of "Testing", but the actual output is error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SplString' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:2
```

Comment: Did you install SplTypes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first install `spl_types` and only then using SplString...

If you have pecl installed, then in terminal just write:

```
sudo pecl install SPL_Types
```

Comment: This is not complete answer, you force OP to use pecl (and you don't offer other solutions). Also you suggest solution only for `Unix-like computer operating systems`

Comment: Can you give a better solution?